# Convert single array to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If a problem i try to solve now some hours, but simply cant find a solution.

If a single array of paths

```
$singleArray = array(
   '/Web',
   '/Web/Test1',
   '/Web/Test2', 
   '/Web/Test2/Subfolder',
   '/Web/Test3',
   '/Public'
);
```

From that array i want to create a mulitdimensional array, which keeps the keys but put subfolders in the correct parent folders. Later i want to loop over the new array to create a folder tree (but thats not a problem)

The new array should look like this:

```
$multiArray = array(
   '/Web'=>array(
      '/Web/Test1'=>array(),
      '/Web/Test2'=>array(
          '/Web/Test2/Subfolder'=>array()
      ),
      '/Web/Test3'=>array()
   ),
   '/Public'=>array()
);
```

Comment: I didn't put the vote, but is this a question asking for logic steps involved? Or simply a request to write code for the OP?

Comment: A good answer will give the logic and probably do so using code (because it's nicer to look at than pseudo-code or flowcharts)

Comment: I dunno what you people are complaining about. This a legit question. The answer can be in pseudo-code you know.

Comment: @OIS: Ive tried a lot. From calling recursive functions, which build each part of the array by exploding the string of each element. But i got allready stucked in the second dimensions which did also contain "/Web/Test2/Subfolder" and other solutions i cant remember anymore. 

SnoApps: I was looking for the logic steps involved and not for the complete solution (even the answer below is one). 

Sorry, iam new here. Next time when ive a question i will try to write a more complete question (even my english is not the best...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below will make the array you want. The key to solve your problem is to create a reference to the array every iteration.

```
<?php
$singleArray = array(
    '/Web',
    '/Web/Test1',
    '/Web/Test2',
    '/Web/Test2/Subfolder',
    '/Web/Test3',
    '/Public'
);

$multiArray = array();

foreach ($singleArray as $path) {
    $parts       = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));
    $section     = &$multiArray;
    $sectionName = '';

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $sectionName .= '/' . $part;

        if (array_key_exists($sectionName, $section) === false) {
            $section[$sectionName] = array();
        }

        $section = &$section[$sectionName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works like a charme. I guess my problem is, that i didnt understand the references correctly. I think i have to dig depper in documentations and tutorials about this. But first i will try to debug the code a bit to understand whats going on here ;)

Comment: Nice solution, I prefer a recursive function instead of your inner `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working! Great challenge!

First I sort the array by number of folders, so that the first to be processed are those with fewest folders (in the root).

Then the function iterates through each of the array items and each folder in that item, comparing it to the existing items in the array and, if it exists, placing it inside of that item as a multidimensional array.

This will work for up to two subfolders - /root/sub1/sub2 - but it's quite straightforward so simple to add functionality for deeper use.

This sample code also prints out the before/after arrays:

```
$singleArray = array(
   '/Web',
   '/Web/Test1',
   '/Web/Test2', 
   '/Web/Test2/Subfolder',
   '/Web/Test3',
   '/Public'
);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($singleArray);

$multiArray = array();


//first sort array by how many folders there are so that root folders are processed first
usort($singleArray, function($a, $b) {

    $a_folders = explode("/", $a);
    $b_folders = explode("/", $b);

    $a_num = count($a_folders); //number of folders in first
    $b_num = count($b_folders); //number of folders in second

    if($a_num > $b_num) return -1;
    elseif($a_num < $b_num) return 1;
    else return 0;

});

//foreach in array
foreach($singleArray as $item){

    //get names of folders
    $folders = explode("/", $item);

    //if the first folder exists
    if(in_array($folders[0], $multiArray)){

        $key1 = array_search($folders[0], $multiArray);

        //repeat for subfolder #1
        if(in_array($folders[1], $multiArray[$key1])){

            $key2 = array_search($folders[1], $multiArray[$key1]);

            //repeat for subfolder #2
            if(in_array($folders[2], $multiArray[$key1][$key2])){

                $key3 = array_search($folders[2], $multiArray[$key1][$key2]);

                array_push($multiArray[$key1][$key2][$key3], $item);

            } else array_push($multiArray[$key1][$key2], $item);

        } else array_push($multiArray[$key1], $item);

    } else array_push($multiArray, $item);

}

//reverse the array so that it looks nice
$multiArray = array_reverse($multiArray);

print_r($multiArray);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /Web
    [1] => /Web/Test1
    [2] => /Web/Test2
    [3] => /Web/Test2/Subfolder
    [4] => /Web/Test3
    [5] => /Public
)
Array
(
    [0] => /Web
    [1] => /Public
    [2] => /Web/Test1
    [3] => /Web/Test2
    [4] => /Web/Test3
    [5] => /Web/Test2/Subfolder
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest i had a quiete similiar solution before. But as you pointed out: It only works until the second subfolder. But i will try to use your code a bit and tweek it to use more subfolders ;)